# How to prevent interruption of audio track playing when power button is pressed in android?

Tags: android

When the power button is pressed the audio track stops playing.
How to prevent audio track stop when power button is pressed.
I tried using keyguard manager to prevent lock when audio track is playing the screen is not locking but still audio track is stopped.
This happening only for certain music files(.wav format).

//Here in below code the audio track is written with bytedata with buffer size of 512KB.

```
public class M_Audio_Class implements Runnable {

private byte[] mByteData = new byte[512];
AudioTrack mAudioTrack;

@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mAudioTrack
                .setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(new AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) {
                        mAudioTrack.write(mByteData, 0, mByteData.length);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       mAudioTrack.stop();
                    }
                });

        //Here NOTIFY_PERIOD_SIZE is 128 samples
        mAudioTrack.setPositionNotificationPeriod(NOTIFY_PERIOD_SIZE);
        //Audio Track playing is intialized here
        mAudioTrack.play();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [keep CPU on by holding a wakelock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu). Do not forget to release lock once done with playback.

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
Wakelock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```